# o:commandScript - update h:panelGroup after push

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I want to use omnifaces push notification which is already working for me.
The only problem is that the container is not updating as soon I got a push notification. Only with a page refresh.

I would like tu update my bell icon:
[Bell Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6s5t.png)

Here my code with the strucuture...
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFoc1.png)

Here my code JSF:

```
    <h:form id="notificationPushTopbarForm">
    <o:socket channel="notificationChannel"
        user="#{loginBean.currentEmployee.id}" scope="view"
        onmessage="someTestScript">
    </o:socket>

    <o:commandScript name="someTestScript"
        actionListener="#{numberOfUnreadNotificationByEmployeeNotLazyController.findNumberOfUnreadNotification()}"
        immediate="true" render="@parent:topbar_container, :notificationTopbarForm" />

</h:form>

    <h:panelGroup id="topbar_container" styleClass="topbar" layout="block">

    <ul class="topbar-menu">

        <li><p:commandLink id="notificationLink" global="true"
                update=":notificationTopbarForm" resetValues="true"
                oncomplete="PF('notificationSidebar').show()" ajax="true"
                process="@this">
                <i class="topbar-icon fa fa-fw fa-bell-o"></i>
                <h:outputText id="notificationTopbar"
                    value="#{numberOfUnreadNotificationByEmployeeNotLazyController.numberOf}"
                    rendered="#{numberOfUnreadNotificationByEmployeeNotLazyController.numberOf != 0}"
                    styleClass="topbar-badge animated FontBold rubberBand" />
                <h:outputText value="Benachrichtungen"
                    styleClass="topbar-item-name" />
            </p:commandLink> <p:tooltip for="notificationLink" value="Benachrichtungen"
                position="bottom" /></li>
```

Any idea what I´m doing wrong

Comment: Did you try `render=":topbar_container :notificationTopbarForm"`

Comment: @Melloware, that was is.... Many many thanks!! Why is there no comma needed?

Comment: OK i posted my solution below if you don't mind marking it accepted.  Are you sure it was removing the comma? (I always use space separated in updates) also it might have been removing @parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the update attribute to the following:

```xml
render=":topbar_container :notificationTopbarForm"
```